# Silverstripe How to get datas in SiteConfig from subclasses

Tags: php, silverstripe

Actualy, i'm using this code from a extended class.

Example :

```
class EcommerceEmail extends Email {
...

    $from = SiteConfig::get()->first()->EcommerceDefaultEmail;

...
}
```

My problem here is the $from variable. It's working, but I don't think this is the best idea.

I have thinked this

```
$this->SiteConfig()->EcommerceDefaultEmail
```

Or this

```
$this->owner->SiteConfig()->EcommerceDefaultEmail
```

My last two code don't work and I don't know why. Is there another way to get EcommerceDefaultEmail in SiteConfig() from a subclass?

Comment: `$this->owner` is only for DataExtensions that are "plugged" to other objects. This is different from subclassing (what you did with `class EcommerceEmail extends Email`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SiteConfig::current_site_config()`. Eg.

```
SiteConfig::current_site_config()->EcommerceDefaultEmail
```